# Logstash - Separate results into different objects using Grok match pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

So currently I'm analysing data from my MySQL subtitles db, and putting them in ElasticSearch 5.2. Regardless, my ES logstash has the following filter:

```
filter {
    grok {
           match => ["subtitles", "%{TIME:[_subtitles][start]} --> %{TIME:[_subtitles][end]}%{GREEDYDATA:[_subtitles][sentence]}" ]
          }
}
```

which produces the following:

```
"_subtitles": {
                  "sentence": [
                     "im drinking latte",
                     "im drinking coffee",
                     "while eating a missisipi cake"
                  ],
                  "start": [
                     "00:00:00.934",
                     "00:00:01.934",
                     "00:00:04.902"
                  ],
                  "end": [
                     "00:00:02.902",
                     "00:00:03.902",
                     "00:00:05.839"
                  ]
               }
```

but what I want is this:

```
 "_subtitles": [
                     {
                          "sentence": "im drinking latte",
                          "start": "00:00:00.934",
                          "end": "00:00:02.902"
                       },
                     {... same structure as above},
                     {... same structure as above},
]
```

Having in mind that _subtitles will be nested by predefined mapping.

And the original data is as follow:

```
00:00:00.934 --> 00:00:02.902
im drinking latte

00:00:01.934 --> 00:00:03.902
im drinking coffee

00:00:04.902 --> 00:00:05.839
while eating a missisipi cake
```

How can I achieve this using Grok's match pattern and placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **So after a lot of research and reading i found *THE ANSWER***

I found the best way to do it is either : 
- Leave Logstash and do my own script for migrating  from mysql to Elastic, but then i'd have to do all the pattern recognition and replacement, which can get somehow complicated.
- post-process the fields with a Ruby script/filter.

The solution was as follow:

```
ruby {
      code => "
        subtitles = []
        starts = event.get('start')
        ends = event.get('end')
        sentences = event.get('sentence')
        counter = 0
        starts.each do |v|
         temp_hash = {}
         temp_hash['index'] = counter
         temp_hash['start'] = v
         temp_hash['end'] = ends[counter]
         temp_hash['sentence'] = sentences[counter]
         counter += 1
         subtitles.push(temp_hash)
        end
        event.set('subtitles', subtitles)
      "
  }
```

Hope that helps.

**But now** i'm trying to improve this, because my ElasticSearch container fails with something like "cannot handle requests"/ goes off for a while.. just because of the indexing (currently around 20k row from mysql) into Elastic with around 40 nested objects for each.

Anything that i can do to make faster?

maybe a way to flag docs so i dont process them and mark them as processed the previous day or some'n ?

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: Btw, here is one-liner for this code:

`event.set('subtitles', event.get('sentence').zip(event.get('start'), event.get('end'), 0..sentences.length-1).map { |t,s,e,i| {'sentence' => t, 'start' => s, 'end' => e, 'index' => i } })`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that better approach is to use [split filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html) first, to split content to separate phrase-events with `split { terminator => "\n\n" }`, and use grok afterwards (which will split single subtitle at a time).

Comment: already spliting, but still have to use grok then use ruby, cause when grok split it will only put them as shown above in the main post.